# calculate when unchecking the checkbox

Tags: html, jquery

I need help to calculate a total when unchecking a checkbox.

Example:

- add 10 to input in ingredient 1, add 10 to input in ingredient 2, add 10 to input in ingredient 3. Total is 30 that works
- uncheck any of the ingredient checkboxes total calculates all inputs values. That I don't know how to do.

Thanks for you help.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // ingrédients allergènes
  $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, 2).hide().val('');
    var list = $('.results > li').hide();
    
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
      list.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
      $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, 2).show();
    });
  }).find('input:checkbox').change();

  $(".tags").on('input', '.txtCal', function() {
    var calculated_total_sum = 0;

    $(".tags .txtCal").each(function() {
      var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
      if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
        calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
      }
    });
    
    $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tags">
  <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-1" class="ingredient"> ingredient 1 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' /><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-2" class="ingredient"> ingredient 2 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' /><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-3" class="ingredient"> ingredient 3 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' /><br>
  <span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b>
</div>
<ul class="results">
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-3">Alpha isomethylionone</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Amyl cinnamal (Jasmonal A)</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Amylcinnamyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Anisyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2">Benzyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Benzyl benzoate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl cinnamate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl salicylate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Butylphenyl methylpropional (Lilial)</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Cinnamal</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Cinnamyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Citral</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Citronellol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Coumarin</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not trivial because your HTML was not helping me.

If we wrap each set of elements in a div you can do this

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tags").on('input', function() {
    var calculated_total_sum = $(this).find(".ingredient").map(function() {
      const chck = $(this).is(":checked")
      const val = $(this).closest("div").find(".txtCal").val()
      return chck ? +val : 0;
    }).get().reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tags">
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-1" class="ingredient"> ingredient 1 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' />
  </div>
  <div> 
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-2" class="ingredient"> ingredient 2 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' />
  </div>
  <div> 
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-3" class="ingredient"> ingredient 3 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' />
  </div>
  <span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b>
</div>
<ul class="results">
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-3">Alpha isomethylionone</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Amyl cinnamal (Jasmonal A)</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Amylcinnamyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Anisyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2">Benzyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Benzyl benzoate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl cinnamate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl salicylate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Butylphenyl methylpropional (Lilial)</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Cinnamal</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Cinnamyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Citral</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Citronellol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Coumarin</li>
</ul>
```